# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' when running cpp program

Tags: c++, mingw

Im installed mingw and vs code on my system , i followed all the steps,added to environment variable and all but when im running simple hello world program it gives this error:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
My code :
#include<iostream
using namespace std;

int main(){

```
cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You have passed the wrong options to the compiler, specifically `-mwindows`. The error indicates that the compiler thinks you are trying to build a Windows GUI program, but your code indicates that you are trying to build a console program. Remove `-mwindows` from your command line.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in VS code

Comment: I'm not familiar with mingw in VSCode, but you need to edit the part of tasks.json where the mingw compiler options are.

Comment: If you can't figure it out then you should post tasks.json as part of the question.